# Ordered List with matrix structure

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

How to create an ordered list vertically as well as horizontally?
[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9fa0.png)

Let's say this list is dynamically generated.So I can't manually enter the numbers along with the select box.

First 5 values should be displayed in the first column,6-10th in the second column and so on(3*5 matrix).Is there a way to do this with counters?

```css
select {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 34px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><select class="form-control">
  <option>Alpha</option>
  <option selected>Alphanumeric</option>
  <option>Numeric</option>
  <option>Constant Values</option>
  </select></li>
  <li><select class="form-control">
  <option>Alpha</option>
  <option selected>Alphanumeric</option>
  <option>Numeric</option>
  <option>Constant Values</option>
  </select></li>
  <li><select class="form-control">
  <option>Alpha</option>
  <option selected>Alphanumeric</option>
  <option>Numeric</option>
  <option>Constant Values</option>
  </select></li>
  <li><select class="form-control">
  <option>Alpha</option>
  <option selected>Alphanumeric</option>
  <option>Numeric</option>
  <option>Constant Values</option>
  </select></li>
  <li><select class="form-control">
  <option>Alpha</option>
  <option selected>Alphanumeric</option>
  <option>Numeric</option>
  <option>Constant Values</option>
  </select></li>

</ol>
```

I don't know how to make the 6th select box appear in the same row as 1st.
Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `column-count`

```
ol {
  column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
}
```

```css
select {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 34px;
}

ol {
  column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 60px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 60px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><select class="form-control">
  <option>Alpha</option>
  <option selected>Alphanumeric</option>
  <option>Numeric</option>
  <option>Constant Values</option>
  </select></li>
  <li><select class="form-control">
  <option>Alpha</option>
  <option selected>Alphanumeric</option>
  <option>Numeric</option>
  <option>Constant Values</option>
  </select></li>
  <li><select class="form-control">
  <option>Alpha</option>
  <option selected>Alphanumeric</option>
  <option>Numeric</option>
  <option>Constant Values</option>
  </select></li>
  <li><select class="form-control">
  <option>Alpha</option>
  <option selected>Alphanumeric</option>
  <option>Numeric</option>
  <option>Constant Values</option>
  </select></li>
  <li><select class="form-control">
  <option>Alpha</option>
  <option selected>Alphanumeric</option>
  <option>Numeric</option>
  <option>Constant Values</option>
  </select></li>
  <li><select class="form-control">
  <option>Alpha</option>
  <option selected>Alphanumeric</option>
  <option>Numeric</option>
  <option>Constant Values</option>
  </select></li>
  <li><select class="form-control">
  <option>Alpha</option>
  <option selected>Alphanumeric</option>
  <option>Numeric</option>
  <option>Constant Values</option>
  </select></li>
  <li><select class="form-control">
  <option>Alpha</option>
  <option selected>Alphanumeric</option>
  <option>Numeric</option>
  <option>Constant Values</option>
  </select></li>
  <li><select class="form-control">
  <option>Alpha</option>
  <option selected>Alphanumeric</option>
  <option>Numeric</option>
  <option>Constant Values</option>
  </select></li>
  <li><select class="form-control">
  <option>Alpha</option>
  <option selected>Alphanumeric</option>
  <option>Numeric</option>
  <option>Constant Values</option>
  </select></li>
  <li><select class="form-control">
  <option>Alpha</option>
  <option selected>Alphanumeric</option>
  <option>Numeric</option>
  <option>Constant Values</option>
  </select></li>
  <li><select class="form-control">
  <option>Alpha</option>
  <option selected>Alphanumeric</option>
  <option>Numeric</option>
  <option>Constant Values</option>
  </select></li>
  <li><select class="form-control">
  <option>Alpha</option>
  <option selected>Alphanumeric</option>
  <option>Numeric</option>
  <option>Constant Values</option>
  </select></li>
  <li><select class="form-control">
  <option>Alpha</option>
  <option selected>Alphanumeric</option>
  <option>Numeric</option>
  <option>Constant Values</option>
  </select></li>
  <li><select class="form-control">
  <option>Alpha</option>
  <option selected>Alphanumeric</option>
  <option>Numeric</option>
  <option>Constant Values</option>
  </select></li>

</ol>
```

Comment: But how to get numbers 6-15 along with this?
It appears only for the first column.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which browser are you using? numbers are appearing for me in firefox.

Comment: I have added `-webkit-column-gap: 60px;` please check.

Comment: Works with -webkit-column-gap.Thanks!